# Spring batch writer throttling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

I working spring batch project, to read records from the DB then write to rabbitmq, then send to HTTP message gateway. The gateway has **150TPS** and I need to limit my application to 150TPS. Is there a way to **throttle with spring batch** or any other better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it:

- On Spring Batch side: using a `ItemWriteListener#beforeWrite`, delay the writing of items using `Thread.sleep` or using a rate limiting library like [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) or [Resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j#ratelimiter)
- On RabbitMQ side: using the [delayed-message-plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange#rabbitmq-delayed-message-plugin) to delay the delivery of messages at the desired rate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used Guava RateLimiter and works even though it has a warning concerning its stability

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with chunk oriented processing by defining the maximum chunk size to your TPS or less than that.

You can refer to the below doc for implementing Spring batch by Chunk Oriented Processing:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html

Hope it helps...

Comment: My dilemma is that chunk may not limit the fetching rate. Even if I set the chunk to 10, spring batch will fetch so many records within a second.