# Spring Batch Partitioning with rate limit

Tags: java, spring-batch

## Background

I'm using Spring Batch to fetch data from our customer sites through HTTP API. The progress contains 2 main steps:

1. Fetch the total documents from API, then calculate the total pages using a configurable page size. Each page will be assigned to one partition step using custom `Paritioner`.
2. A partition step will send a request to fetch page of data (a list of documents), process and write to our storage.

Customer sites might be *"fragile"*. They could have rate limit or their sites might not respond after some heavy requests.

## What I have done so far

I'm using `spring-retry` to re-run a request which is failed because of rate limit or server error. For e.g:

```java
// the partition step's item reader
@StepScope
public class CustomItemReader extends ItemReader<Object> {
  private List<Object> items;
  @Override
  public Object read() {
    if (Objects.isNull(items)) {
      this.items = ImportService.getPage(pageId);
    }
    if (Objects.nonNull(items) && !items.isEmpty()) {
      return items.remove(0);
    }
    return null;
  }
}

// config retry for fetching function
public class ImportService {
  @Retryable(
      value = RetryableException.class,
      maxAttempts = 3,
      backoff = @Backoff(
          delay = 1000
      )
  )
  public static List<Object> getPage(String pageId) throws RetryableException {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

The retry config contains `Backoff` policy, which has an incremental delay (1000 ms). I used this `Retryable` to handle both retry and rate limit.

## Problem

1. `Retryable` will repeatedly wait and re-execute the function, which hold the thread for the whole time. The instance might crash when things get bigger.
2. Because each customer will have its own rate limit, using `Retryable` with `Backoff` is not an ideal way to control the rate. Eventhough I config `core_pool_size` for each customer sites, `core_pool_size=1` is not enough for some.

## Question

1. Is there any proper way to throttle the execution rate of Spring Batch, especially with Partitioning? For e.g: I want to config to send 2 requests in 10 seconds, and this will not be achieved by using `sleep` in step listener.
2. I have used `scrapy` for some crawlers, and it has pretty cool retry and rate limit features. With [RetryMiddleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry), it will enqueue the failed pages and has a `RETRY_LIMIT` in settings. With [AutoThrottle](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html), it can automatically throttle speed based on load on server. Is there any way to achieve kind of those features in Spring Batch? Or I have to rewrite my project with `scrapy`?

**Thanh you very much!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch does not provide such features. But you can use any rate limiting library where appropriate during the step (ie before/after reading data, before/after processing or writing data, etc).

This should help: [Spring batch writer throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923083/spring-batch-writer-throttling).