# Google Indexing API rateLimitExceeded

Tags: spring-batch, google-indexing-api

I have a Spring Batch Process which submits something around 5M urls to Google Indexing API. In the past, the process was segmented e parallelized int two threads by an attribute, one for the small segments and one for the bigger. From some days ago up to now, it was refactored to submit request as it come from a query response (sorted by its priority, ignoring the previous segmenting attribute, using a single thread to execute). After that refactoring, I started getting a "rateLimitExceed" error from Google API. I have (by contract) 5M request a day and I'm submitting batches of 500 urls a time. The average sending time is around 1.2 seconds for each 500 urls batch.

Does anybody know what may be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I did not do the math, but if you are getting this exception, it means you are exceeding the limit. Depending on where you are doing the API call (ie in the item writer or in an item processor), you can do the math and delay the call as needed with a listener to not exceed the limit.

You can find a similar question/answer here: [Spring batch writer throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923083/spring-batch-writer-throttling)

Comment: First, thanks a lot for your answer... API doc says you can do 10 requests per second... actually I'm doing less than one. Yet, considering the previous parallel processing, it was faster and didn't get those errors.